# Add a formula to Google Sheets pivot table

Tags: google-sheets

I have a report that I rerun with new data every day. I need to publish it in Google, but part of the table is a formula and I do not want to have to recreate this formula in the body every day.

How do you create a formula that can be part of a Google Sheets pivot table?

Answer (score 2):

> How do you create a formula that can be part of a Google Sheets pivot table?

Here is an example:

[image: WA59771 example]

It is very simple not only because just for illustration but also because Calculated Fields are not the place for complex formulae.